# angularjs: can't get scope variable value from the ng-template in controller

Tags: ng-template

In my project, I use angularjs to develop a webapp, and I use ng-template in the project as following:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id = "searchbox.html">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><input ng-model = "searchedCity" type="text" class="form-control" id="searchcity" placeholder = "Search City">
</div>
</div>
</script>

<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="candidatecity">Cities</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-options="city for city in avaiablecities" ng-model="selectedCity" id="candidatecity" ></select>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="selectedCity=='Others'" ng-include="'searchbox.html'"></div>        
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="period">Time Period</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <select class="form-control"  ng-options="period for period in avaiableperiod" ng-model="selectedperiod" id="period"></select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clickSendRequest()">Get Data</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
```

There are some cities listed in the city commobox, and the final is "Others", if the target city is not inside the list, user should input the city by themself into the input text box, which is controlled by `ng-if`. And it works ok.

But the problem is that I can't get the user input data of the search box. I set the `ng-model = "searchedCity"` directive, but in the following JS code, I can't get its value.

```
MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


$scope.avaiablecities = ["Mexico City","Los Angeles", "Toronto", "Frankfurt", "Milan", "Mumbai", "Chicago", "Paris", "Beijing","Dubai","Sydney","Singapore","Hong Kong","Tokyo","New York","London","Amsterdam","Kuala Lumpur","Brussels","New Delhi","Johannesburg","Others"];
$scope.avaiableperiod = ["Past One Week", "Past One Month","Past One Quarter","Past One Year"];


$scope.clickSendRequest = function() {
    // send geocoding request to the API 

    console.log($scope.selectedCity);
    if ($scope.selectedCity == "Others") {
        console.log($scope.searchedCity);
    } else {
        console.log($scope.selectedCity);
    }   
};
```

})

the output of `console.log($scope.searchedCity)` is undefined. 
So what is the problem?

EDIT:
After long time debugging and a lot googling about the communication between controllers. I find the root cause
 
`<div ng-if="selectedCity=='Others'" ng-include="'searchbox.html'"></div>` 
In the above tag, `ng-if` and `ng-include` are used to realize the desired effect on the page. But it brings in more concerns in angularjs. Since both `ng-if` and `ng-include` generate a deeper or sub-level `scope`. So in this case, the ng-template is the child of the child of the main controller. 
so the solution is `$parent`. So do it as following, can make it work well for me
`ng-model = "$parent.$parent.searchedCity"`

Comment: anyone can help me here?

Comment: Bro were you able to find the resolution. Even I am struck here from long time. Please help